# Installing Bootloader/Grub2 on USD with Ubuntu on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows

I have a Lenovo y510p system with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. It has UEFI with secure boot and I want to dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I am not a too tech savvy person and want to look at the Ubuntu flavor if it suits me enough to move.

I tried installing the GRUB2 on the "/sda" (my main HDD) but after I boot to windows even once, the GRUB2/bootloader no longer starts. To prevent any mess up of my system (read Windows 8.1 loader), I plan to install the Ubuntu bootloader on an USB. It would be great if any one can help me with the following on the same:

1. I plan to re-install Ubuntu 14.04.2, so during installation can I go to "Something Else" and use my main HDD (/sda) for installing the Ubuntu (i.e. "/" and "/home") while use an USB flash drive to install the "/boot" (boot loader) partition ?
   Can the above be done, I mean to what mount point is the "/sdb" flash drive be mounted for it to install the GRUB2?
2. If the above is possible will I need to always plug in the USB once I have booted in Ubuntu or I can simply remove it after Ubuntu has started?
   This mean that the "/boot" is no longer on the system.

Over all is there any way I can install Ubuntu on HDD such that when the USB is not plugged in I go to my Windows system and when I plug in the USB I can boot to GRUB2 menu on the USB and go to Ubuntu. Will the above scheme work ? Please do correct me, as I know I can be wrong.

Thanks in advance for all the help I have already found on the Ask Ubuntu forums.

Thanks and Regards
Ankit

Comment: Come on guys, any suggestions ? I am a newbie and Googled till my wits allowed, but surprisingly this big forum and this hype about Ubuntu and I could not get a single suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do is here :
http://tinyurl.com/mdpfzpo

Also you can read :

1. For the first question this link might help you a little bit http://tinyurl.com/q6tm77t
2. If you'll install the bootloader on USB, then the USB will have to be always plugged in whenever the computer starts.

   The link below could be also useful
   http://tinyurl.com/ozo5tz8